# How to make a button that changes your website theme and saves using cookies?

Tags: cookies, themes

Basically what I want to know how to do is to make a button that, when clicked, changes the theme (colors) of my website, and stays like that when the users goes to the website again using cookies. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it saves it in a cookie but hope it helps a little. Its not a bad little script i use it myself.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

Update: Never mind it does use cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, have a link for each of your themes that link to a page like this:

```
<a href="setTheme.php?theme=black">Black</a>
```

Then on the setTheme.php, set a cookie that stores their selection:

```
setcookie("userStyleSheet", $_REQUEST["theme"]);
```

Finally, when you print out your HTML link to the CSS, print out the correct CSS file

```
<?php
$cssFile = ($_COOKIE["userStyleSheet"] != "")?$_COOKIE["userStyleSheet"]:"default";
echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/path/'.$cssFile.'.css" />';
?>
```

If you are not using PHP, it goes basically the same for any other server side language.